# MySQL WHERE column = everything in Laravel framework

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table called `vacancies` and the following query. I want to get `city_id` which equals to any value. So I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM vacancies WHERE vacancies.city_id=vacancies.city_id
```

It works perfect when I run it from `phpmyadmin`. However it does not work when I run it via `laravel` framework code like that:

```
DB::table('vacancies')->select('*')->where("vacancies.city_id","=","vacancies.city_id")->paginate(5);
```

I do need to run query like `where column=column`.
How can I do that in Laravel? Or what is wrong with my laravel coding?

Comment: no where required simply "SELECT * FROM vacancies"

Comment: You have to put in that where clause?  It's meaningless, and it might as well be absent.  Have you tried leaving it out?

Comment: That should yield the same result as SELECT * FROM vacancies. i would just use that if I were you

Comment: `SELECT * FROM vacancies WHERE city_id IS NOT NULL`

Comment: As I mentioned in my explanation, due to structure of my code I do need to run query with "where column=column". I know that I can also use "SELECT * FROM vacancies".

Comment: Use `whereRaw('vacancies.city_id = vacancies.city_id');` instead of `where()`. Also `select('*')` is implied so it's not really necessary.

Comment: you may have solved but its far from a good idea, it will slow the query down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the query without any `select` and `where` like [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects)

`DB::table('vacancies')->get();`